# How to increase the location accuracy when the object is moving

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

Actually, I am doing a gps application that will measure the distance between two geopoints while moving. However, when my device is static, there will still be distance calculated as the location changed will update the old and new geopoints, then calculate the distance.
Below is the setting I used in my program:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
```

When locationChanged, it will do update the old and new GeoPoint and calculate the distance.

And, I am using network provider for testing indoor.

Please kindly advice as I really need some helps. Thank you.

Comment: what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: when I am not moving, it the current location should be the same location, but it will update to other location.

Comment: that is in the nature of the system... location calculation is "fuzzy" so small changes are absolutely to be expected !

Comment: @Yahia, you are lucky if want this jumping behaviour but iphone supresses location while standing still.